# Lodash uniqBy multiple for array?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I have array:

```
[ [ '245', '0', '0.0100', '245,0,0.01' ],
  [ '245', '1', '0.0100', '245,1,0.01' ],
  [ '208', '0', '0.0300', '208,0,0.03' ],
  [ '208', '0', '0.0500', '208,0,0.05' ],
  [ '208', '0', '0.0600', '208,0,0.06' ] ]
```

and i need to get unique arrays by `[0]` and `[1]` cells
like this:

```
[ [ '245', '0', '0.0100', '245,0,0.01' ],
  [ '245', '1', '0.0100', '245,1,0.01' ],
  [ '208', '0', '0.0600', '208,0,0.06' ] ]
```

Help please/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use lodhash **[`uniqBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs#uniqBy)** method

```js
var data = [
  ['245', '0', '0.0100', '245,0,0.01'],
  ['245', '1', '0.0100', '245,1,0.01'],
  ['208', '0', '0.0300', '208,0,0.03'],
  ['208', '0', '0.0500', '208,0,0.05'],
  ['208', '0', '0.0600', '208,0,0.06']
];

console.log(
  _.uniqBy(data, function(v) {
    return v[0] + ' ' + v[1];
  })
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.13.0/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: @axon : glad to help :)

Comment: i got [ '208', '0', '0.0300', '208,0,0.03' ]  maybe it possable specify reverse for unique element? get ['208', '0', '0.0600', '208,0,0.06']

Comment: @axon :  reverse the array and do the same